# Flashlight turns itself off while a recording video on iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone

I'm using FiLMiC to record a 30 minute video.

In FiLMiC, I turn the flashlight on and hit the record button.

(the iPhone has is the power cord connected).

After about 20 minutes the flashlight just turned itself off!

Is this some overheating issue? I can't find any documentation to suggest that it is. It's very annoying!

Answer (score 1):

> The iPhone flashlight uses the iPhone flash to illuminate your path.
>   This uses an LED to provide the light, which lasts longer than a bulb
>   you would place in your house or one that you would find in a cheap
>   flashlight.
>
> According to Bulbs.com, “Many LEDs have a rated life of up to 50,000
>   hours.” To put that in perspective, a typical LED can last almost six
>   years of constant use. It is unlikely that you will use the iPhone
>   flashlight for six year’s straight, so there is little chance of the
>   iPhone flashlight burning out or damaging your iPhone camera flash.

http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/02/16/iphone-flashlight-tips/

The best to do is to contact the application's Developers to report the issue ;)